# How to install "elastix: a toolbox for rigid and nonrigid registration of images" in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, installation, libraries, binary-files

I have downloaded [Mac OS X 64 bit binaries](http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/download_links.php) for [Elastix](http://elastix.isi.uu.nl) and tried to run `./elastix` in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite):

```
$ cd elastix_macosx64_v4.7
$ tree
.
├── CopyrightElastix.txt
├── bin
│   ├── elastix
│   └── transformix
└── lib
    └── libANNlib.dylib
$ cd bin
$ ./elastix
dyld: Library not loaded: libANNlib.dylib
  Referenced from:    
/Downloads/elastix_macosx64_v4.7/bin/./elastix
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

The same result appears after running `./transformix`.

Is it necessary to do some steps before executing them? Or is something needed in relation to `libANNlib.dylib`?

Answer (score 0):

In the elastix user manual, it says to add the following lines to .bashrc:

```
export PATH=folder/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=folder/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

On MacOS, it's not exactly the same but I got it to work by editing ~/.bash_profile and adding these two lines:

```
export PATH=folder/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=folder/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

where "folder" is the path to the elastix folder.

Hope this helps.